# MediaStore.Audio.Media.RECORD_SOUND_ACTION not working in nougat

Tags: android

I am using MediaStore.Audio.Media.RECORD_SOUND_ACTION to open sound recorder application, I am not able to open application as no default application present, then i install two voice recorder application even though not able to see these application in my chooser intent. I am using following code-

```
Intent soundRecorderIntent = new Intent();  // create intent
soundRecorderIntent.setAction(MediaStore.Audio.Media.RECORD_SOUND_ACTION);  // set action
startActivityForResult(soundRecorderIntent, ACTIVITY_RECORD_SOUND); // start activity
```

It works well in marshmallow

Comment: Please edit your question and provide a [mcve], as perhaps there is something wrong with your `Intent`. However, there is no requirement for every voice recorder app to support this `Intent` action.

Comment: @CommonsWare i have posted the actual code i am using..

Answer (score 1):

The code is correct and you've probably found an app that supports the intent by now. But to prevent that others waste their time like I did, here's a quick note:

**Most of the currently top rated voice recording apps in the Play Store do not provide the necessary intent filter.**

That seemed so unrealistic to me that I doubted my code when it didn't work after having installed the five most popular voice recording apps. But there's a handy manifest viewer app that reveals that their manifests simply do not declare the intent filter. So, as said, the code is correct.

To save you the time from searching for a suitable app, here are two that are invocable:

- *Audio Recorder* from Sony
- *Samsung Voice Recorder* from Samsung

Comment: I also did very same. But I could not find those apps you have suggested on Google Play. Could you please share a link

Answer (score 0):

There is no requirement for a voice recorder app to support this `Intent` action, and apparently your device does not ship with an app that supports this `Intent` action either. Your code itself seems fine.

If recording is optional to your app, catch the `ActivityNotFoundException` and tell the user that they do not have a recorder, and perhaps suggest to them that they install one that you test that works, if you can find one.

Otherwise, record the audio yourself, using `MediaRecorder`.

Comment: or use resolveActivity method on the intent before starting the activity and check for null, if null it means there is no activity available to resolve that intent thus saving you from try catch